# Azure Kubernetes - Enforce only one deployment per node?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

I'm currently creating a Kubernetes cluster in Azure Kubernetes for a production environment. In my cluster, I will have 2 nodes in the node pool - pool1.

Now, I want to deploy 2 applications however both the application will use the container port 5000 and I will not be able to change the ports due to some reasons.

For simplicity, I kept the same manifest for both deployments except the name of the deployment

**Deployment manifest - 1:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

**Deployment manifest - 2:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.16.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

As both the deployments uses the same containerPort, the 2nd deployment fails as it is deployed on the same node where 1st app is deployed.

I want to enforce a policy where only one deployment (but not restricting other pods like proxy, sidecar) is allowed per node in Azure Kubernetes.

At the end, deployment-1 should go to node-x and deployment-2 goes to node-y, please suggest.

Comment: Howdy. Just a heads-up. You can have all your deployments on the same port. Each deployment results in pods being created. The pods each get their own IP address and can listen on any ports.

If you're looking at exposing these pods you can use a Kubernetes service. Services can do port mapping. You can again listen on any port (services have their own DNS name and IP address in the cluster) and point the traffic to any port.

Comment: If you're planning on listening on the host port then the port needs to be unique - but only for the Kubernetes service, not the deployment's container port.

Comment: which essentially means the above mentioned scenario is uncommon, correct?

Comment: Have you considered using [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector)? That way you could decide on which node the pods from particular deployment would be scheduled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could use in your case is the [nodeSelector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector):

> `nodeSelector` is the simplest recommended form of node selection
> constraint. `nodeSelector` is a field of `PodSpec`. It specifies a map
> of key-value pairs. For the pod to be eligible to run on a node, the
> node must have each of the indicated key-value pairs as labels (it can
> have additional labels as well). The most common usage is one
> key-value pair.

`nodeSelector` is one of the forms of node selection constraint. `nodeSelector` is a field of PodSpec. This is a simple Pod scheduling feature that allows scheduling a Pod onto a node whose labels match the `nodeSelector` labels specified by the user.

There are also [Affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) as well as [Inter-pod affinity and anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) that you could consider using. Notice the [More Practical Use-cases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#more-practical-use-cases) as it should fit your requirements:

> Interpod `Affinity` and `AntiAffinity` can be even more useful when they
> are used with higher level collections such as ReplicaSets,
> StatefulSets, **Deployments**, etc. One can easily configure that a set of
> workloads should be co-located in the same defined topology, eg., the
> same node.

You can find more details and examples in the linked documentation.